# Ionic 3 File Plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, angular, file, ionic-framework

I want to save *JSON* data into a file.

I tried to follow the [usage guide for file storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) which lead to below code:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

this.file.writeFile("data/", "Kategorien2.json", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Whne trying to run this code, I get the error below:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for File: (?, ?).
```

What can I do?

Comment: have you added File as a provider in your module?

Comment: have you imported this in app.module.ts

Comment: I added
providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        SocialSharing,
        File,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]

Answer (score 0):

the error is showing because you did not add the options parameter for the writeFile method. Use this code for your purpose =>

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
this.file.writeFile("data/", "Kategorien2.json", JSON.stringify(data), {replace : true});
```

*Here I used replace option for writeFile, true means it will replace the file, false means it will not replace the file.*

Comment: Didn't changed anything. Same Error.
My IDEA (PHPStorm) says "writeFile" is an "unresolved function or method"
and for the import "@ionic-native" "can't resolve directory" but it is existing

Comment: I would suggest to use VSCode for development I used sublime, atom and webStrorm but VSCode is best.